# Macro to make a backup while saving a file

Tags: vba, excel

I would like to have a macro which automatically makes the backup of my file to a different folder when it is being saved. I have found a working macro but it makes a copy each time when I run it (not automatically when file is being saved). Could anyone help me to amend the macro code to work as I described?

MACRO I HAVE:

```
Sub Auto_Save()

Dim savedate

savedate = Date

Dim savetime
savetime = Time
Dim formattime As String
formattime = Format(savetime, "hh.MM.ss")
Dim formatdate As String
formatdate = Format(savedate, "DD - MM - YYYY")

Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Dim backupfolder As String
backupfolder = "Z:\My Documents\"
ActiveWorkbook.SaveCopyAs Filename:=backupfolder & formatdate & " " & formattime & " " & ActiveWorkbook.Name
ActiveWorkbook.Save
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
MsgBox "Backup Run. Please Check at: " & backupfolder & " !"

End Sub
```

Comment: So, what have you tried? Why not just skip the part that adds the date and time to the filename?

Comment: The msgbox would annoy me immensely. Depending on the version, Office has some built-in backup functionality, you find it (in 2010) in options - save.
Of you want to use the macro, take a look at the save event of the workbook...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You mean you just want one backup-file with the same name as the original? Just remove the date and time from filename of the backup copy:

```
ActiveWorkbook.SaveCopyAs Filename:=backupfolder & ActiveWorkbook.Name
```

You should also add some kind of error handling in case the backup file is open when trying to save etc.

**EDIT** (updated based on new input)

OK, then you need to trap an event. I've tried with the `BeforeSave` event and it works. There is also an `AfterSave` event you could try.

Add the following to the `ThisWorkbook` module:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
    Dim backupfolder As String

    backupfolder = "Z:\My Documents\"

    ThisWorkbook.SaveCopyAs Filename:=backupfolder & ThisWorkbook.Name
End Sub
```

Comment: No I mean i don't have to run the macro each time i want to make a backup. Macro stays enabled and each time when somebody saves the file it makes the backup. With the current macro to make a backup you need to click RUN MACRO and nothing happens when I save the file

Comment: @mgunia using the Workbook_beforeSave [event](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_(computing)), it will trigger the code every time before you save the excel, you don't have to run the macro manually.

Comment: @Olle Sjögren it works great! Exactly as I wanted. Thank you for a help. Larry, my answer to Olle before was about his pre-edited post. After he edited the post now it changes everything

Answer (score 4):

Here's the code I created to backup my workbooks.  It will create a subdirectory for your backups if it doesn't exist, and save backups to that directory.

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
    Application.EnableEvents = False

    thisPath = ThisWorkbook.Path
    myName = Left(ThisWorkbook.Name, (InStrRev(ThisWorkbook.Name, ".") - 1))
    ext = Right(ThisWorkbook.Name, Len(ThisWorkbook.Name) - InStrRev(ThisWorkbook.Name, "."))
    backupdirectory = myName & " backups"

    Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    If Not FSO.FolderExists(ThisWorkbook.Path & "/" & backupdirectory) Then
        FSO.CreateFolder (ThisWorkbook.Path & "/" & backupdirectory)
    End If

    T = Format(Now, "mmm dd yyyy hh mm ss")
    ThisWorkbook.SaveCopyAs thisPath & "\" & backupdirectory & "\" & myName & " " & T & "." & ext

    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```