# Excel macro runs in personal.xls but not in any other workbook

Tags: vba, excel

I have placed the following macro in my `c:\program files (x86)\microsoft office\office11\xlstart\personal.xls`:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
' http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15267796/macro-to-make-a-backup-while-saving-a-file
' http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/deploy-your-excel-macros-from-a-central-file-HA001087296.aspx

  Dim BackupName As String

  MsgBox "ActiveWorkbook.Name: " & ActiveWorkbook.Name   'For debugging
  BackupName = ActiveWorkbook.Name
  BackupName = Mid(BackupName, 1, InStrRev(BackupName, ".")) & "bak"
'For testing    BackupName = "D:\temp\" & BackupName    'For testing
  BackupName = ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & BackupName

  ActiveWorkbook.SaveCopyAs BackupName
End Sub
```

From what I understand (e.g. second link mentioned above) this is supposed to run every time I save any worksheet, but this is not happening.
Only if I (edit and) save personal.xls do I see the `MsgBox` and the `personal.bak` file appearing.

What am I forgetting?

(Running W7 64-bits and Office 2003).

Comment: No, this is a *Workbook*-level event, it is only raised when the specific workbook is saved (the one containing the code, in your case, Personal.XLS)

Comment: Have you had a chance to try my suggestion below?

Comment: Not yet, have to do that in my 'spare' time. It's just a home project.

Answer (score 1):

I mentioned in the comments that what you have is a workbook-level event procedure. That is slightly different from a "macro" (your public macros would be available to any open workbook, but the worksheet or workbook-level events would not respond to *other* workbook events).  What you need is to trap **Application-level events**.

I have not fully tested this but i did some simple test and it seems to work, (I am porting over some code that I use in PowerPoint to trap Application-level events).  Give this a shot and let's see if it works for you.

**First** create an class object to handle the events.

In your Personal.XLS, add a Class module and name it `cEventClass` (you can name it wahtever you want, but it will be easier to follow my example if you use the same naming conventions that I'm using).

In this class module, put the following code:

```
Option Explicit
Public WithEvents XLEvent As Application


Private Sub XLEvent_WorkbookBeforeSave(ByVal Wb As Workbook, ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)

'This is just my test, you can place your own code (modified as needed) here:
MsgBox "BeforeSave " & Wb.Name

End Sub
```

We've now established the means to trap Application-level events, and we can see these available options in the dropdowns in the VBE:

[image]

**Next**, instantiate an instance of this class.

Probably the best place to do this will be during the Personal.XLS `Workbook_Open` procedure.  You could put it in another sub and call it on-demand, etc., but if you put it in this event handler, I think it should work.

Add a normal code module (this can't go in an object or class module), do this:

```
Public cXLEvents As New cEventClass
```

**Add some code to automatically instantiate the class**

in the Workbook_Open procedure of your Personal.XLS, do this:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    'Add this line in addition to any other code you might already have in this procedure
    Set cXLEvents.XLEvent = Application

End Sub
```

**Now, sit back and let the handler do its job!**

Now, when you go to save *any* workbook (not limited to the Personal.XLS) the Application event handler should pick it up, as verified with my example:

[image]

**NOTE** I think this will fail to work if you are debugging and "End" run-time; that will kill the `cXLEvents` and so the event handler will essentially be turned "off", so you would need to re-instantiate it.